# How to install Oracle driver on Apache Superset (without internet access)

Tags: oracle, cx-oracle, apache-superset, instantclient

I opened this question as a large number of people fail to install Oracle driver on Apache Superset with or without internet access.

Answer (score 0):

## To install Oracle driver on Apache Superset (without internet access) you will need to :

- Install cx_Oracle python package on docker container
- Install Oracle Client libraries on docker container

### 1. How to install cx_Oracle python package on docker container (without internet access)

- Download cx_Oracle python package (WHL) for docker container python version and architecture (**cx_Oracle-8.2.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl**) and move your file on **/superser/docker/** folder.
- Create a **requirements-local.txt** on **/superset/docker/** folder and add **/app/docker/cx_Oracle-8.2.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl** in it.
- That's all. When you will use **docker-compose up** command, the package will be installed on docker container.

### 2. How to install Oracle Client libraries on docker container (without internet access)

- Use **docker-compose down** command.
- Download **libaio1_0.3.112-3_amd64.deb** package from Debian website.
- Download Oracle Client libraries **rpm** package from Oracle website (**oracle-instantclient-basic-21.1.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm**).
- Install **alien** on a linux computer (**sudo apt-get install alien**).
- Use alien to transform your **rpm** package on a **deb** one with **alien --to-deb oracle-instantclient-basic-21.1.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm** command.
- Start Apache Superset with **docker-compose up** command.
- Identify the id of your Apache Superset docker container with **docker container ls** command.
- Move your **libaio1_0.3.112-3_amd64.deb** package to your container with **docker cp libaio1_0.3.112-3_amd64.deb [CONTAINER_ID]:/app/** command.
- Move your Oracle Client libraries package to your container with **docker cp oracle-instantclient-basic-21.1.0.0.0-2_amd64.deb [CONTAINER_ID]:/app/** command.
- Install package on docker container with **docker exec [CONTAINER_ID] dpkg -i /app/libaio1_0.3.112-3_amd64.deb** command.
- Install package on docker container with **docker exec [CONTAINER_ID] dpkg -i /app/oracle-instantclient-basic-21.1.0.0.0-2_amd64.deb** command.
- That's all. You can now connect Apache Superset to your Oracle database.

Comment: Instead of setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH, simply use the `alien` option `--scripts`.  This will copy the Instant Client post install setup that runs `ldconfig` to set the system library search path.  This helps avoid problems with apps that clean the environment when they run.