# Apache Superset and Oracle connectivity

Tags: apache-superset

I am trying to establish a connection between Apache Superset and Oracle. I am trying to follow the steps mentioned in the below stack overflow post:

[How to install Oracle driver on Apache Superset (without internet access)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68182176/how-to-install-oracle-driver-on-apache-superset-without-internet-access)

But when I add the .whl file to the requirements-local.txt file and restart docker, I am getting an error saying that the wheel is not supported.

Any help regarding this issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you copied the .whl name from that installation guide it is more likely to be  that your version of python is not python3.7, because this wheel `cx_Oracle-8.2.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl` is for python3.7 as you may see cp37 it tells you that this wheel is meant for python3.7, you need to check the version of python and then install the proper package for it.